# Reading floats from a file in R

Tags: r

I have a file with float values separated by tabs:

> $ head file.data

```
1756.38 378.6   0.0
1754.2  378.62  0.0
1752.79 378.52  0.0
1751.3  378.43  0.0
1756.38 378.71  0.0
1762.2  378.41  0.0
1760.38 378.32  0.0
1763.38 378.6   0.0
1763.38 378.49  0.0
1762.29 378.41  0.0
```

However, when I load the file in my R script I lose the decimal part of the first field:

> f <- read.table('file.data', sep="\t", header=FALSE, dec=".")
>
> head(f)

```
    V1    V2 V3
1 1756 378.6  0
2 1754 378.6  0
3 1753 378.5  0
4 1751 378.4  0
5 1756 378.7  0
6 1762 378.4  0
```

How can I load the file without losing part of the information?

Thank You.

Comment: Please post the results of `str(f)`.  This is probably just rounding at print time, rather than an import problem.

Comment: else you can try: adding the parameter `numerals="no.loss"`

Comment: + str(f)
'data.frame': 2464 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: num  1756 1754 1753 1751 1756 ...
 $ V2: num  379 379 379 378 379 ...
 $ V3: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

Comment: I get an error if I add the parameter: the argument was not used (numerals = "no.loss")

Comment: @phonixor where should I put this parameter? Because I've tried and it does not work.

Comment: @Andrie, the output of the function is the same that I had.

Comment: Please post the results of `options("digits"); options("scipen")`

Comment: @Andrie  **> options("digits")  $digits  [1] 4  > options("scipen")  $scipen  [1] 0**

Comment: OK, that's your problem.  You've configured R to only print 4 significant digits, which is precisely what you see.  Try `options(digits = 7)`

Comment: @Andrie Thank you! So, it was only a representation problem?

Comment: Correct.  This is what I suspected in my very first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, the presentation of information is different from the underlying storage of information.

For example, you can use the `digits` option to control the number of significant digits:

```
> print(3.1415928, digits=2)
[1] 3.1

> print(3.1415928, digits=4)
[1] 3.142

> options(digits=4)

> print(3.1415928)
[1] 3.142

> options(digits=7)

> print(3.1415928)
[1] 3.141593
```

The default in R is:

```
> options(digits=7)
```

Try setting your digits option to a higher number.